# Reinstall Windows Service from same Windows Service

Tags: c#, installation, windows-services

I need to reinstall my Windows service from same service. And installable version can be a previous version, so RemovePreviousVersion flag in setup project not going to work.

If I start the uninstall process from same service, my service will be stopped, and I can't to start another process to install desired version.

Is there any other way other than creating bat-file to uninstall and install required version from it?

Comment: You won't be able to reinstall a service without stopping it thats for sure. Is this all intended to be automated? How will you be notifying the service that it needs to update itself?

Comment: Can't the service start its own executable, only with different command line arguments? Upon seeing those, the executable would, instead of registering with the service manager, stop the service, delete it, and reinstall itself.

Comment: I do not want to use the additional executable files except for the service. I'm starting and stopping the service using InstallerCustomActions in setup project (at commit and beforeUninstall). It's work as well, but if I uninstall itself, there is no way to run installer process from itself.

Comment: Service is need to update automatically by command from server.

Comment: Now I create a bat file that removes the service, and then installs the desired version and removes itself and the installer. But it is in fact crutches. And if during installation something goes wrong, it can not be corrected remotely.

Comment: Don't use a batch file, that's asking for trouble.  (What if the sysadmin has disabled batch processing?)  Use the service executable, copied to a temporary location and run with a command line argument that tells it what to do.

Comment: But how can I start a service with different arguments? It must re-register, but with a different path (which I will copy it)? And how to programmatically change the arguments to start the service - only through the registry?

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand what you mean. I need to add to Program.Main parameter "string [] args", and if the arguments are not empty, do not run the service itself, and execute the service uninstall operation and install another version. I understand you correctly?

Comment: If you are using MSI package created by Visual Sudio you will not be able to install previous version when a new version is already installed. But if you want MSI to install new version directly after uninstalling previous version that is possible and I have sample code. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @OrkunBekar Yes, it will also help. I would be grateful for the sample code.